# Getting indices of list based on a second list

Tags: python

I have a list `a` which contains all the possible values in list `b`

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

and

```
b = ['baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']
```

I'd like to return a list `c` which has the number of elements found in `b` where each element is the index of `a` in for which the value of `b` can be found.

Example

```
c = [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Did you try anything for it?, also if the value cannot be found, what should be in `c`?

Comment: I can find a particular value if I do something like `[i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == "foo"]` but not all values

Comment: `print([a.index(i) for i in b])`

Comment: `[a.index(item) for item in b]` use `list.index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner:

```py
c = [a.index(x) for x in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> b = ['baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']
>>> [a.index(i) for i in b]
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]
```